# Rails filter index results by using a link (without dropdown)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If a user selects a predefined filter link, how would my index show results based on that request?

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %>
<% end %>

<h2>Find Product by Category</h2>
Electronics
Apparel
Books
```

For example, how would I make "Electronics" link to filter the products index to only include products with an "Electronics" category? The "category" field/column is already defined in my database/model.

This is currently what my controller looks like:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make your links a link back to the products, but add category as a url parameter.

Then in your controller, if the parameter is present, filter results based on it.  Such as:

View:

```
<h2> Find Product by Category </h2>
  <%= link_to "Electronics", products_path(:category=>"electronics")
```

Controller

```
def index
  if params[:category]
    @products = Product.where(:category => params[:category])
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

Based on comment by egyamado :

If you want to add flash messages it would be something like this:

```
def index
  if params[:category]
    @products = Product.where(:category => params[:category])
    flash[:notice] = "There are <b>#{@products.count}</b> in this category".html_safe
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

If you only want to show the message if there are no products, then just add `if @products.empty?` to the end of the flash designation

Or you could make it completely conditional if you want to show an error message if there are no products and a notice if there are products

```
def index
  if params[:category]
    @products = Product.where(:category => params[:category])
    if @products.empty?
      flash[:error] = "There are <b>#{@products.count}</b> in this category".html_safe
    else
      flash[:notice] = "There are <b>${@products.count}</b> in this category".html_safe
    end
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @trh, vote up. In your solution, when a category is been selected , all related products will get displayed. And when no category is been selected, show all products. But, how you go about choosing a category that has no products, where let's say it shows all products with flash message lets say: "No products available for Electronics!"?  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your post.  It was perfect for my needs also

I am using it in a link
`<td><%= link_to 'Show', candidates_path(:atc_name=>(atc.name)) %></td>`.